# Encase signal by getting the upper and lower envelope in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation, envelope

I have a signal that bounces around some values. I want to encase the signal from above and below as seen in the following figure:
[image: example]

If the signal only grows or decreases, using a running maxima script works great:

```
function [out] = rMax(X)
    Y=X;
    maximum=X(1);
    for k=1:length(X)
        if X(k)<=maximum
        Y(k)=maximum;
        else
            maximum=X(k);
        end
    end
    out=Y;
end
```

However, when the signal alternates, I cannot use that method anymore. Is there a way to achieve this in MATLAB or Mathematica?

Comment: For this function or any other, I would strongly advise you NOT to use a variable named `max` as it shadows a Matlab built-in function and may cause all sort of hard to debug issues, specially when it is done unknowingly.

Comment: yeah I know, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`movmax`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmax.html) and [`movmin`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmin.html) in conjunction with appropriate window sizes `n1` > `n2` depending on your needs. *These two functions were introduced in R2016a. Have a look at the bottom of my answer for a self-written replacement for them that works prior to R2016a.*

To get the *upper bounds*, you can use:

```
xMax = movmax(x,[n1,n1]);
xMax = movmin(xMax,[n2,n2]);
```

For the *lower bounds*, just switch `movmin` and `movmax`:

```
xMin = movmin(x,[n1,n1]);
xMin = movmax(xMin,[n2,n2]);
```

The result can look like this:

[image: result]

If you choose `n2=n1`, the bounds are very tight when there is a peak in the data `x`. In case you choose a bigger difference by just making `n2` smaller than `n1`, you will get a longer straight line at the peak. A side effect is that the bounds start to be distanced when the signal jumps from 1 to -1 or vice versa. If `n1` is chosen too high, the small part of the signal around 100 won't be extracted.

---

Here is the complete code to generate the above figure with some sample data matching the plot in your question. Just play around with the values `n1` and `n2` to see their effect.

```
n1 = 20;        % for first window
n2 = 18;        % for second window

% generate sample data
t = 20:0.1:220;
x = -ones(size(t));
x(t>60&t<100) = 1;
x(t>105&t<135) = 1;
x(t>145&t<155) = 1;
x = x + 0.4*randn(size(x));

% get upper bounds
xMax = movmax(x,[n1,n1]);
xMax = movmin(xMax,[n2,n2]);

% get lower bounds
xMin = movmin(x,[n1,n1]);
xMin = movmax(xMin,[n2,n2]);

% draw figure for illustration
figure; hold on;
plot(t,x);
xlim([20,220]);
ylim([-3,3]);
plot(t,xMax,'r','LineWidth',1.1);
plot(t,xMin,'Color',[0,0.5,0],'LineWidth',1.1);
```

---

#### Prior to R2016a

To have the *basic functionality* of `movmin` and `movmax` in MATLAB versions prior to R2016a, we can implement our own functions. Therefore, we need to apply a moving-minimum (or moving-maximum respectively) which can be achieved quite easily. In order to maintain compatibility with the functions in R2016a, we are going to implement the case where the second argument is a scalar and where it is a vector of two elements. This covers the following syntax similar as seen [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmax.html) with the restriction that `x` needs to be a vector.

```
y = movingmax(x,k)
y = movingmax(x,[kb kf])
```

Here is the code for `movingmax` that replaces `movmax`:

```
function y = movingmax(x,n)
if length(n) > 1
    a=n(1); b=n(2);
else
    b=floor((n-1)/2); a=b+mod(n-1,2);
end
s = size(x);
xp = [ones(a,1)*x(1);x(:);ones(b,1)*x(end)];
y = zeros(size(x));
for k = 1:length(x)
    y(k) = max(xp(k:k+a+b));
end
y = reshape(y,s);
```

Here is the code for `movingmin` that replaces `movmin`:

```
function y = movingmin(x,n)
if length(n) > 1
    a=n(1); b=n(2);
else
    b=floor((n-1)/2); a=b+mod(n-1,2);
end
s = size(x);
xp = [ones(a,1)*x(1);x(:);ones(b,1)*x(end)];
y = zeros(size(x));
for k = 1:length(x)
    y(k) = min(xp(k:k+a+b));
end
y = reshape(y,s);
```

Comment: Your answer looks to do exactly what I was looking for. The only bad thing is that movmax and movmin functions work for matlab2016a, I currently have only access to 2015 version.

Comment: @JaredLo I just updated my answer to include a solution that works for versions prior to R2016a. See the part in the bottom, which offers a replacement for the two functions. The results are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I add a second condition to my running maxima/minima functions

```
function [out] =rMin(X)

Y=X;

minimum=X(1);

for k=2:length(X)

    if X(k)>=minimum
        Y(k)=minimum;
    else
        minimum=X(k);
    end

    if X(k)>=(Y(k-1)+3)
        minimum=X(k);
        Y(k)=minimum; 
    end
end 

out=Y;

end
```

and i get this however still fails at some parts of the signal 
[image]